# Select value from one column based on three criteria and display each criteria in each column

Tags: vba, ms-access

How to select the column value based on three criteria. I want each criteria display in each column. Is it possible?

Database is Ms-Access

My Table is:

## ID  Name    Key  Keyer_Type

```
1   xxx 565  Beginner
8   yyy 456  Beginner
1   xxx 4589     Skill
9   zzz 89   Beginner
2   uuu 8789     Expert
8   yyy 5689     Skill
```

Using distinct and groupby clause I select the unique vaue in ID no and corresponding name. 
    I want to select the key based on beginner, skill, expert on separeate column.

My need my output as:

```
ID  Name    Beginner    Skill  Expert#

1   xxx 565 4589    
8   yyy 456 5689    
9   zzz 89      
2   uuu         8789
```

How to display the Beginner, skill, expert as a separate column from Keying level column.

Comment: I don't understand anything...

Comment: Hi I want to reterive the data based upon the column(name- Keying) value... My column have three citeria(beginner, Skill, Expert). I want to display these critera into three columns(beginner- one columns and skill in other column like wise expert.. )

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is exactly what you need, but I think this is close to the answer you need:

```
TRANSFORM First(TableName.Key)
SELECT TableName.ID, TableName.Name
FROM TableName
GROUP BY TableName.ID, TableName.Name
PIVOT TableName.Keyer_Type;
```

**Edit** as per the comment:

This will return a grouping on the ID, and the first corresponding name.

```
TRANSFORM First(Table2.Key)
SELECT Table2.ID,First( Table2.Name)
FROM Table2
GROUP BY Table2.ID
PIVOT Table2.Keyer_Type;
```

But it is not clear to me what the meaning of `Name` is.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply.. While I am using the above query I have duplicate value in ID. My output would be unique in ID. Kindly help on this.

Comment: I am grouping by ID, Name. To obtain a unique ID, the pairs (ID,Name) must be unique, in other words, only one Name should match to one ID. I am guessing that you might have different names per ID?

Comment: Yes, my single id have different name. Please assist me to return the unique value of id.